# Is there a way of using breakpoints in python?

Tags: python, debugging, breakpoints

I am just wondering if there is a way to add breakpoints in IDLE so that I can stop at a point in my script and write other lines in the idle shell for testing. If not, is there other software that can do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can add the line

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

anywhere in your code, when reached it will drop you into a debug shell. so useful i have an emacs shortcut to add the snippet.

you may also want to look at  [ipdb](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipdb), and use

```
import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
```

instead

Answer (score 3):

http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Windows, you might look at [PyScripter](http://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/) if you want a development environment with more features than IDLE.

Comment: +1 only been using PyScripter for about a half hour, but am already preferring it over IDLE